# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Invalid Padding length

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, wsdl

I am getting this exception when trying to execute a webservice over https. This exception occures the movement I try to get the service instance.
I followed the below steps for generating the webservice client using wsImport.exe tool.

1. I manualy downloaded the wsdl from the site
2. Used wsImport tool to generate the client java files
3. Added the java files to my project in eclipse
4. Wrote a test client as below to test the service instance

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String certificatesTrustStorePath = "c:/Apps/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/security/cacerts";
       // if I don't set the store path, I get below error 
       //javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
       //sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
       //sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", certificatesTrustStorePath);

       URL wsdlLocation = null;
       String https_url ="https://localhost/services/WebService/wsdl/WebService.wsdl";
       try {
           wsdlLocation = new URL(https_url);

       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
       } 

       //This is the line where I get the below execption 
       WebServiceService webServiceService = new WebServiceService(wsdlLocation, 
           new QName("http://webservice.com", "WebServiceService"));  

   }
   ```

With the above code I below execption

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Invalid Padding length: 76
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Invalid Padding length: 50

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.webservice.WebServiceService.<init>(WebServiceService.java:42)
at com.client.Client.main(Client.java:46)
```

Everytime I execute, the numbers in the front ot "**Invalid Pad length**" is different. this time it is 76 and 50. other time it was 67, 106. etc

Please help,
I am using latest version of Java i.e. 1.8.0_51.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Java 8 has this issue... tested with Java 7. Same code is working fine.

Comment: This solution isn't very well explained as some pieces of code are not compatible with Java 7. @seneque posted a community thread with much more information. While there doesn't seem to be a clear answer, according to the bug report on https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8013059 disabling Diffie Hellman key exchanges worked. This is also not a surefire solution, but might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

It seems similar to this problem: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2506695

Have you tried using bouncycastle?

Comment: Where should I use the bouncycastle?